# Why am I getting a white border around button on running application in c#

Tags: c#, user-interface, interface

[image]

When I start my application, I am getting a white border around the button in my form. And when I click anywhere else on the form, the button becomes normal. I have used flat style on the button and did not put a border myself to the button. It seems like this border is caused by the tab button. How can I remove this weird border from my application.

Here are the settings for the button.

```
  this.homeButton.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles) 
  (((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | 
  System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.homeButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.homeButton.BackgroundImageLayout = 
 System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
        this.homeButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.homeButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = 
 System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(231)))), ((int)(((byte) 
 (76)))), ((int)(((byte)(60)))));
        this.homeButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.homeButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 
 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 
 ((byte)(0)));
        this.homeButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.homeButton.Image = 
 global::CEFSharpBrowserTesting.Properties.Resources.user_icon_16;
        this.homeButton.ImageAlign = 
 System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.homeButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 12);
        this.homeButton.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 33);
        this.homeButton.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 33);
        this.homeButton.Name = "homeButton";
        this.homeButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 33);
        this.homeButton.TabIndex = 3;
        this.homeButton.Text = "    Home";
        this.homeButton.TextImageRelation = 
        System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
        this.homeButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.homeButton.Click += new 
        System.EventHandler(this.homeButton_Click);
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include your relevant source code, so that the community can replicate your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @MandyShaw Thanks. But there is no relevant code to this problem. It is just a simple button with no border. But I am getting this border around the button. I suppose this is caused due to the tab key because later when I navigate through the TAB key on my keyboard, it shows a similar border like this.

Comment: OK - maybe provide a screenshot of the configuration of the button, then.

Comment: @MandyShaw Sorry for not putting that early. Done!. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm just the 'triage person' endeavouring to make it as easy as possible for the community to help you.

Comment: @MandyShaw Well thanks anyways!